# How to get the index of element in IntVar using java choco3 API?

Tags: java, constraint-programming

I am trying to solve the Meeting Scheduling Problem. I have defined a matrix `IntVar[][] agent_cal` that is the calendar of each of the agents whose meetings are to be scheduled. My initialization is the following:

```
agent_cal=VF.boundedMatrix( "agents' calendar",
                                       mAgents,
                                     timeslots,
                                            -1,
                                   nMeetings-1,
                                       solver);
```

where mAgents, timeslots, nMeetings are given and solver is an instance of Solver. I want to place the constraint that for every meeting; all the agents that attend the meeting must have it in their calendars at the same timeslot. For example if `agent0` and `agent1` attend meeting `m`, then index of `agent_cal[agent0]` where m appears must be equal to the index of `agent_cal[agent1]` where m appears.

To express this in choco, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
for (int m = 0; m < nMeetings; m++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> as = meet_attend.get(m);
    for (int a = 0; a < as.size() - 2; a++) {
        solver.post(ICF.arithm(
                    (Arrays.asList(agent_cal[a])).indexOf(m),
                                "=",
                    (Arrays.asList(agent_cal[a+1])).indexOf(m)));
    }
}
```

What I get are the following errors:

```
Solve.java:136: error: cannot find symbol
              solver.post(ICF.arithm((Arrays.asList(agent_cal[a])).indexOf(m),"=",(Arrays.asList(agent_cal[a+1])).indexOf(m)));
                                                                                         ^
symbol:   variable Arrays
location: class Solve
Solve.java:136: error: cannot find symbol
                solver.post(ICF.arithm((Arrays.asList(agent_cal[a])).indexOf(m),"=",(Arrays.asList(agent_cal[a+1])).indexOf(m)));
                                        ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class Solve
2 errors
```

Any ideas on how to fix this will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *arithm* constraint can link a variable and an integer, or two variables together, or two variables and an integer together.
In your case, `(Arrays.asList(agent_cal[a])).indexOf(m)` returns an integer, so does `(Arrays.asList(agent_cal[a+1])).indexOf(m)`, and there is no API to express that two integers must be equal, since they are not variables.
I believe you want to get the m^th column of `agent_cal` variable matrix, and link the variables `a` and `a+1` in the same column.
If so, you can do that like:

```java
import org.chocosolver.util.tools.ArrayUtils; 
//....
for (int m = 0; m < nMeetings; m++) {
    IntVar[] colm = ArrayUtils.getColumn(agent_cal, m);
    ArrayList<Integer> as = meet_attend.get(m);
    for (int a = 0; a < as.size() - 2; a++) {
        solver.post(ICF.arithm(
                colm[a],
                "=",
                colm[a+1]));
    }
}
```